# How to get last two URL segments?

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

What is the best way to get the last two URL segments?

To get the last segment is pretty easy `url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`

Here is an example, say I have this url `http://mywebsite/segment1/segment2`

So I want to get `segment1/segment2`

Is there a better way than just using `url.split("/");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [joining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is probably the easiest:

```js
const url = 'http://mywebsite/segment1/segment2';

const lastTwo = url.split('/').slice(-2).join('/');

console.log(lastTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a reference :

[image]

Take out the pathname, and then do the string.split, it would also protect you from the content after the `?` sign (url parameters).